# show mapview based on user specified coordinates

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an app in iphone. in my app I have a map view which is showing user current location on map and also displaying longitude and latitude coordinates. Now I want to edit the coordinates and according to that mapview should update the location on map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by edit?

Comment: it means I want to enter coordinates manually now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]try this reference Tutorial

[Current Location & MapView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-drop-a-pin-on-map-with-mapkit-api/)

Let me know if you have any problem.

**updated Answer**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
placeCoord.latitude=Your Latitude;
placeCoord.longitude=Your Longitude;

//Pass this where
//userLocation.coordinate is written in the tutorial
userLocation.coordinate = placeCoord;
```

**Updated Answer2**

[Mapview](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)animateMapToLocation:(CGFloat)latitude (CGFloat)longitude
{
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
 coordinate.latitude=latitude;
 coordinate.longitude=longitude;

  [yourMKMapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:YES];

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: its not working..........

Comment: I hope you have all your delegate set. Check for the latitude and longitude value that you are receiving.